# How do I read data from the Flutter Firebase Real-Time Database?

Tags: flutter, dart

I've used the Real-Time Database with this setup:

```
->users
->uid
    ->name
    ->email
    ->other info
```

If I wanted to save the user data I would use my User class and then set the object in the database like this:

`final FirebaseUser user = await FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser();
FirebaseDatabase.instance.reference().child("kullanıcılar").child(user.uid).child("takip").set({"uid":"uid"});`

I tried it and it works fine.

But how can I retrieve these values from the database? For instance, once I set a User object as shown above, I may want to retrieve the user's email. I don't mean getting the email through the sign-in provider. I want the email through the real-time database. I've tried working this out for a while now but the documentation isn't helping much. All it shows is to setup listeners in order to wait for changes to the data. But I'm not waiting for changes, I don't want a listener. I want to directly get the values in the database by using the keys in the JSON tree. Is this possible via the real-time database? If so, how can it be done because either the documentation doesn't explain it or I'm just not understanding it.Thanks.

Comment: you want data after you created that user? in User Table? right?

Comment: hi bro, user table already exists

Comment: Yes, table is already exist I know, I am asking that you want that data from user table, the data which you inserted just now?

Comment: yes, I just wanted to print a single data from Firebase, it won't be in the form of a list.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can retrieve the value once using `.once()`. Here's an example: https://github.com/flutter/plugins/blob/master/packages/firebase_database/example/lib/main.dart#L62

or better, with async/await:

```
Future<String> getEmail() async {
  String result = (await FirebaseDatabase.instance.reference().child("path/to/user/record/email").once()).value;
  print(result);
  return result;
}
```

Comment: do I will to print to a text?

Comment: It's a string, you can do whatever you want with it. I edited my code to make it print before returning it. You can use this in your own async code as `String email = await getEmail();`.

Comment: `Future<String> getEmail() async {
    FirebaseUser user =  await FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser();
    var userid =user.uid;
     String eposta = await getEmail();
    return  (await FirebaseDatabase.instance.reference().child("kullanıcılar/$userid/eposta").once()).value;

  }` i did that

Comment: `Container(
            padding: EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 260),
            alignment: Alignment.center,
            //margin: EdgeInsets.all(130),
            child: Text("$eposta", style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white, fontSize: 13, fontFamily: "SegoeBold" ),),
          ),`

Answer (score 1):

You can't retrieve the single value from firebase, it always return the `DocumentSnapshot` of the whole record. You can get a single record from user table by using user id like this:

```
getData() async {
  final FirebaseUser user = await _firebaseAuth.currentUser();
  return await FirebaseDatabase.instance.reference().child('user').equalTo(user.uid);
}
```

Get it like this:

```
getData().then((val){
    print(val.email);
});
```

Comment: I don't use FireStore.I am using RealTime Database.